# Python script import error in node js application

Tags: node.js, python-3.x

if I am using the python script in **nodejs** application.if you click the button that time python script called. python script contains some import libraries. that library does not support my **nodejs** application.

I already try child_process in node js application.

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import json

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
print("Output from Python") 
print("First name: " + sys.argv[1]) 
print("Last name: " + sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell)

```
import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', null, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

Comment: I am getting the import error while running a python script through python-shell and also through child_process. Any idea how to fix this issue? I couldn't find a solution.Kindly help!